# PHP and highcharts: add mysql results as new column in CSV file

Tags: php, csv, highcharts

I'm trying to prepare code which will run every hour and retrieve some DB data. I would like to store it as csv file and use it to create chart from highcharts. **Problem:** I'm unable to create csv file which will be updated every hour according to this model:

```
01:00, 02:00, 03:00
dataA-01, dataA-02, dataA-03
dataB-01, dataB-02, dataB-03
```

So next column '04:00' with rows dataA-04 and dataB-04 will be added on 4am.

What I got:

```
class liveData 
{
    public $newCsvData = array();

    /*some sql here*/

    public function getHour() 
    {
        $hour = date('H:i');
        array_push($this->newCsvData, $hour);
    }

    public function getDataA() 
    {
        /*...*/
        array_push($this->newCsvData, $dataA);
    }

    public function getDataB() 
    {
        /*...*/
        array_push($this->newCsvData, $dataB);
    }

    public function saveCsv()
    {
        print_r($this->newCsvData);
        $fp = fopen('./tmp/test.csv', 'a+');
        fputcsv($fp, $this->newCsvData, ','); 
        fclose($fp);
    }

}
```

The result of **print_r($this->newCsvData)** is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21:00
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 40
)
```

The code works, but created test.csv looks of course like this:

```
21:00,12,40
21:01,15,45
21:03,18,62
```

and I need to get:

```
21:00,21:01,21:03
12,15,18
40,45,62
```

My problem might seems trivial, but really - and unfortunately - I've spent hours on this. I just can't imagine the proper way. Even if I'm able to get something like

```
21:00
12
40
```

Data on next hour is added to new line like this.

```
21:00
12
40
21:01
15
45
```

Should I use multidimensional array? Should I change fopen() from a+ to other option? 

Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Why you dont use a json, which is easier to use ?

Comment: I will check it;) Is it easier to use also live data from json for multiple line chart?

Comment: Yes, because in the php you can return formatted correctly json, use json_encode() and then in javasript load ($.getJSON()) without any additional parsing.

Comment: I've created already different basic chart with live data using json_encode(). I still can't figure it out how to create live chart with 2 lines (with data as described above). I would like to accomplish something like here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels but with live data like here: http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm using json_encode() with 3 parameters: time and 2 values (1 value for 1 line). Should I use 2 separate files with json_encode() function? Do you know maybe some examples on which can I rely?

Comment: Ok, found it - maybe someone will use it in the future: in my case I'm using 3 elements array for json_encode, this code works in my chart:             `var values = eval(point);
                   chart.series[0].addPoint([values[0], values[1]], true, shift);
                   chart.series[1].addPoint([values[0], values[2]], true, shift);` Thanks again for getting me back from csv idea.

Comment: you need to create correct structure of arrays in php, then return json.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, from a logical perspective, I would use per row the output you have on this moment: dd-mm;data,data,... Is it logical to have the times on the X-axis?
This would also mean you can use the append modus.

If you really want to keep the desired output then I would create an array per row something like:

```
$arr[0][] = '21:00';
$arr[1][] = 'data_b';
$arr[0][] = 'data_b';

$new_data = '';
foreach($arr as $row)
{
   $new_data .= implode(',', $row);
}
```

Note that you cannot use the append modus in this last situation that easily and that this might result in the need to retrieve more data from the database...

Answer (score 1):

print_r($this->newCsvData) shoud be look like this:

```
$data = array(
    array( '21:00' ),
    array( '12' ),
    array( '40' ),
);
```

and in second step, shoud be look like this:

```
$data = array(
    array( '21:00', '21:01' ),
    array( '12', '15' ),
    array( '40', '40' ),
);
```

and third step, same:

so who you can do this. Each time you import all data from CSV file and push each cell to the corresponding array and look like this

```
$newArray = array(array(), array(), array());
foreach($dataFromCSV as $data)
{
   array_push($newArray[0][], $data[0]);
   array_push($newArray[1][], $data[1]);
   array_push($newArray[2][], $data[2]);
}
```

and then append the new record data in $newArray. delete the old data from CSV file and write on it with new data from $newArray.

:) enjoy